# Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }'

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

When I try to fetch data from Google Analytics, I got error

> Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" :
>   "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or
>   scope in request." }'

I create project in my https://console.developers.google.com/project, create  **Service account** and download .p12 key. Also enable "Analytics API" in project settings, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
    $service_account_name = '<Service Email>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    $key_file_location = '<keyName>.p12';
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
        array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS),
        $key,
        'notasecret',
        'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
        '<My email>'
    );
$client->getAuth()->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$result = $service->data_ga->get("ga:<profileID>", "yesterday", "today", "ga:pageviews");
print_r( $result);
```

What is wrong with my project? Please help.

Comment: Did you add the project to your domain? add the clientId and scopes?

Comment: No, I ididn't. Could you tell me, where I need add this parametres?

Comment: Has anyone ideas, what's wrong with my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the final step which is giving access to your application in the control panel of your domain.

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation

You created the service account, now you need to delegate/authorize the application.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I am trying to use Gmail for WP SMTP plugin in WordPress website to send emails. But after following each steps it shows errro

Comment: Mailer: Gmail
{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Unauthorized"
}